# digital zoom iphone / digital zoom general

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Anyone has sample code or know of a tutorial on how to do a digital zoom for an iphone? or digital zoom in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider these [Categories for `NSImage`](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSImageCategory) for ways in which you can zoom and crop an image in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

The crudest forms of digital zooms simply scale an image larger and crop to a certain visible region.  On the iPhone, you can do this easily by capturing an image from the camera, placing it in a UIImageView, and applying a scaling transform to the view.